# Is there any way I can define a variable to calculate total value in for loop in LaTeX

Tags: macros, counters, loops

I'm creating quotation report and use for loop to list product. But the problem is I've to calculate total value by myself then I tried to create variable and sum every time in loop like this

```
\usepackage{calc}

\newcounter{sum_price}

%in for loop
\setcounter{sum_price}{sum_price+price}

%display value
\sum_price$
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui. Also, can you please expand the code snippets that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). It is much easier to help you you if we can start with some compilable code that illustrates your problem -- or a reasonable sketch. In this case, we have to guess which of the many of for-loops you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

In TeX you can use the following:

```
\newcount\sumPrice
\sumPrice=1
\newcount\price
\price=5
\advance\sumPrice by \price
```

In LaTeX you might use:

```
\newcounter{sumPrice}
\setcounter{sumPrice}{1}
\newcounter{price}
\setcounter{price}{5}
\addtocounter{sumPrice}{\theprice}
```

You might also use `\numexpr` (in TeX):

```
\newcount\newprice
\newprice=7
\advance\sumPrice by \numexpr\price+\newprice\relax
```

or in LaTeX:

```
\newcounter{newprice}
\setcounter{newprice}{7}
\addtocounter{sumPrice}{\numexpr\theprice+\thenewprice}
\setcounter{newprice}{\numexpr\theprice+\thenewprice}% this also works
```

In TeX there are also `\multiply` and `\divide`:

```
\multiply\sumPrice by 2
\divide\sumPrice by 2
```

Please also note, that you shouldn't use `_` as part of a variable name.

Example using both in a LaTeX-document (and displaying the results):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
    \newcount\sumPrice
    \sumPrice=1
    \newcount\price
    \price=5
    \newcount\newprice
    \newprice=7
    \advance\sumPrice by \price
    \the\sumPrice
    \advance\sumPrice by \numexpr\price+\newprice\relax
    \ %just to put one space here
    \the\sumPrice

    \newcounter{sumPrice}
    \setcounter{sumPrice}{1}
    \newcounter{price}
    \setcounter{price}{5}
    \newcounter{newprice}
    \setcounter{newprice}{7}
    \addtocounter{sumPrice}{\theprice}
    \thesumPrice
    \addtocounter{sumPrice}{\numexpr\theprice+\thenewprice}
    \thesumPrice

    %in a loop:
    \noindent
    \sumPrice=0
    \loop\ifnum\price>0
        \advance\sumPrice by \price
        \advance\price by -1
        \the\sumPrice\\
    \repeat
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Counters (integers) are not very good to calculate prizes (which have a dezimal part). I would suggest to use the (new!) xfp-package and siunitx to display the numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xfp,siunitx}
\sisetup{locale=DE}

\newcommand\mysum{}
\newcommand\clearsum{\renewcommand\mysum{0}}
\newcommand\addprice[1]{\xdef\mysum{\fpeval{\mysum + #1}}\SI{#1}{EUR}}
\newcommand\showsum{\SI{\mysum}{EUR}}

\begin{document}
\clearsum

\addprice{1.3} + \addprice{2.3} + \addprice{4.99} =  \showsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't even thought of the problematic of decimals when I provided my answer! Very good answer therefore.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what sort of loop you are using, but perhaps you want to produce "product tables" like this:

[image]

Here is one approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgf}

\def\process#1:#2!{% two arguments separated by a colon and ending with !
   \pgfmathparse{add(\producttotal,#2)}% add to total
   \xdef\producttotal{\pgfmathresult}% remember total
   #1 & #2\\% add to table
}
\newcommand\Products[1]{%
  \gdef\producttotal{0}% initialise total as 0
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\process##1!}% loop iteration is delegated to \process
  \begin{tabular}{lr}
      \toprule Product & Price\\\midrule% heading
      \docsvlist{#1} \midrule% add the products
      Total & % now add the total
      \pgfmathparse{\producttotal+0}% annoyance to get right precision!
      \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]\pgfmathresult\\ \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

  \Products{
    Chocolates: 4.99,
    Flowers: 14.99,
    Wine: 24.99
  }

\end{document}
```

Some comments:

- The macro `\Products` accepts a coma separated list of "products", which we will "loop" over. Each "product" is itself a colon separated product name and price
- The total price of the products is stored in `\total`, which is effectively just string. LaTeX does not play well with decimal numbers, which is why I used [pgfmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfmath) for the calculations. Unfortunately, it is not particularly accurate, which is why I have used `\pgfmathprintnumber` to print the numbers to two decimal places (in the MWE it prints `44.97002` without this!)
- The `\xdef\producttotal{\pgfmathresult}` is necessary to ensure that the total is remembered as we run through the loop
- I am using the "looping command" `\docsvloop` from the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package. It loops over a comma separated list and passes the "loop variables" to the command `\do`. The only tricky/non-standard bit here is that `\do` needs to separate the product name and price, which it does using `\process`.
- I have used [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) to make the tables look nicer