# How to create a table macro that takes more than 10 arguments

Tags: tables, macros, lists, xparse, arguments

I want to create a macro that creates several tables. In the example below, the command that creates the tables `\chungeltable` will use one argument for each column in the table (More than 10 columns). Each argument contains a comma separated list which has to be the information of each row:

```
\chungeltable{1,2,3}{a,b,c}{one,two,three}{uno,dos,tres}{um, dois, três}{um,dois,treis}{Eins,zwei,drei}{Ett, två, tre}{un, deux, trois}{En, to, tre}
```

I'm using the following approach ([See My previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369441/table-macro-with-2-or-more-arguments)).

However, as it is not possible to define more than 10 arguments I am getting the error:

```
"kernel/bad-number-of-arguments"Function '\chungeltable' cannot be defined with 10 arguments"
```

Here is my table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\chungeltable}{mmmmmmmmmmm}
{%
\begingroup\scriptsize
\begin{longtable}{ | p{4cm} | p{3cm} | *{13}{l|} p{3cm} | }

    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Name} &
    \multirow{3}{*}{Description} &
    \multicolumn{14}{c|}{Observation} \\
    \cline{3-16} 
    &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{B}  &    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} & E & \multirow{2}{*}{F} & \multirow{2}{*}{G} & \multirow{2}{*}{Other} \\
    \cline{3-13} 
    &  & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & & & \\ \hline
    \endhead
    \chungeltablebody{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}{#a}{#b}
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
 \NewDocumentCommand{\chungeltablebody}{mmmmmmmmmmm}
{
      \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
      \int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { \clist_count:n { #1 } }
      {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l_tmpa_tl
       {
        \clist_item:nn { #1 } { ##1 } &
        \clist_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } &
        \clist_item:nn { #3 } { ##1 } &
        \clist_item:nn { #4 } { ##1 } & 
        \clist_item:nn { #5 } { ##1 } & 
        \clist_item:nn { #6 } { ##1 } & 
        \clist_item:nn { #7 } { ##1 } & 
        \clist_item:nn { #8 } { ##1 } & 
        \clist_item:nn { #9 } { ##1 } & 
        \clist_item:nn { #a } { ##1 } &
        \clist_item:nn { #b } { ##1 }
        &  &  &  &  & 
     \exp_not:n { \\ \hline }
     }
    }
     \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl    
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \chungeltable{1,2,3}{a,b,c}{one,two,three}{uno,dos,tres}{um, dois, três}{um,dois,treis}{Eins,zwei,drei}{Ett, två, tre}{un, deux, trois}{En, to, tre}

\end{document}
```

My question is: How can I define more than 10 arguments in a table, where each argument represents the columns of the table and each item in the list represents the information in the rows?

Comment: I knew we'd arrive to this. You're taking a wrong approach to the matter.

Comment: the syntax `#1` to `#9` and the limit to at most 9 arguments is built in to tex and can not be extended in a macro package such as latex.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to do but this might be related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367892/is-there-any-way-i-can-define-a-variable-to-calculate-total-value-in-for-loop-in/367904#367904

Comment: @egreg Is it possible to parse the commands in `\chungeltablebody` with other command? like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/253517/how-to-make-more-than-9-argument-commands-work-with-tabular) If not, which approach would you recommend for a longtable like this?

Comment: Does it have to work in `longtable`?  That is, does it have to span across page boundaries?

Comment: Hi @steven-b-segletes, thanks for replying! Yes, I'm using landscape mode and longtable because I want to avoid that the tables are cut off at the bottom of each page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the question asks about absorbing more than 10 arguments, the real motivation of the OP, looking at the question, is "how to input `tabular` data by column, rather than by row, including for cases that exceed 9 columns?"

Being no expert in `multicolumn` and `multirow`, I don't know how to restore the final vertical line after the last column of the table, but here, I show how to digest a table by column, rather than by row, even if the number of columns exceeds 9.

I use the `listofitems` package to parse the column-wise data, and then set up a double loop to transpose the data into the standard row-wise format and place it in the token register `\transposedtoks`.  Finally, I just regurgitate `\the\transposedtoks` into the long table.  I show it here with 13 columns.

Data input format is currently

```
\chungeltable{1,2,3&a,b,c&one,two,three&uno,dos,tres&um, dois, três&
um,dois,treis&Eins,zwei,drei&Ett, två, tre&un, deux, trois
&En, to, tre&eleven,th,col&twelve,th,col&thirteen,th,col}
```

however, the `&` column separator and `,` row separator can be changed by editing the line `\setsepchar{&/,}`.  The `listofitems` magic occurs in the macro `\transposedata`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow,longtable}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\NewDocumentCommand{\chungeltable}{m}
{%
\transposedata{#1}%
\begingroup\scriptsize
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
\begin{longtable}{ | p{4cm} | p{3cm} | *{13}{l|} p{3cm} | }
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Name} &
    \multirow{3}{*}{Description} &
    \multicolumn{14}{c|}{Observation} \\
    \cline{3-16} 
    &  & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{A} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{B}  &    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{C} &
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{D} & E & \multirow{2}{*}{F} & \multirow{2}{*}{G} & \multirow{2}{*}{Other} \\
    \cline{3-13} 
    &  & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 & 13 & & & \\ \hline
    \endhead
    \the\transposedtoks
\end{longtable}
\endgroup
}
\newtoks\transposedtoks
\newcommand\transposedata[1]{%
  \transposedtoks{}%
  \setsepchar{&/,}%
  \greadlist*\rawdata{#1}
  \foreachitem\y\in\rawdata[1]{%
    \foreachitem\x\in\rawdata[]{%
      \ifnum\xcnt>1\transposedtoks\expandafter{\the\transposedtoks&}\fi%
      \edef\tmp{\rawdata[\xcnt,\ycnt]}%
      \expandafter\transposedtoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\the\expandafter\transposedtoks\tmp}%
    }%
  \transposedtoks\expandafter{\the\transposedtoks\\\hline}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\chungeltable{1,2,3&a,b,c&one,two,three&uno,dos,tres&um, dois, três&um,dois,treis&Eins,zwei,drei&Ett, två, tre&un, deux, trois
&En, to, tre&eleven,th,col&twelve,th,col&thirteen,th,col}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an example of using `\transposedata`, without all the chungeljumbo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\newtoks\transposedtoks
\newcommand\transposedata[2][&/,]{%
  \setsepchar{#1}%
  \transposedtoks{}%
  \greadlist*\rawdata{#2}
  \foreachitem\y\in\rawdata[1]{%
    \foreachitem\x\in\rawdata[]{%
      \ifnum\xcnt>1\transposedtoks\expandafter{\the\transposedtoks&}\fi%
      \edef\tmp{\rawdata[\xcnt,\ycnt]}%
      \expandafter\transposedtoks\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\the\expandafter\transposedtoks\tmp}%
    }%
  \transposedtoks\expandafter{\the\transposedtoks\\\hline}%
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\transposedata[&/\\]{a\\b\\c&d\\e\\f}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
\the\transposedtoks
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]