# LaTeX macro for summing numbers

Tags: macros, variable

I have a very simple LaTeX problem which confuses me. I want to write a macro which creates a running total of given numbers. The answer by Ulrike Fischer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367892/is-there-any-way-i-can-define-a-variable-to-calculate-total-value-in-for-loop-in) is almost exactly what I want - simple and without extra packages. This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand\mySum{0}
\newcommand\clearSum{\renewcommand\mySum{0}}
\newcommand\addToSum[1]{\xdef\mySum{\fpeval{\mySum + #1}}}

\newcommand{\newNumber}[1]{
    \addToSum{#1}
    % Print number:
    #1 \\
}   
    
\newenvironment{RunningCount}
{
    % Open environment:
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{c}
}
{
    % Close environment:
    \endtabularx
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{RunningCount}
        \newNumber{0.435}
        \newNumber{0.764}
        Total: \mySum
    \end{RunningCount}
\end{document}
```

This produces twice the actual value. (It seems that sometimes it results in other multiples, but in this simple example above it is always twice).

I can fix it by adding

```
\begin{document}
    \clearSum
    ...
```

to the above. But ideally I do not want to do this.

This seems to be an issue with tabularx - if I remove the tabularx from the environment, it works fine. As commented, tabularx must be evaluating its contents multiple times (twice in this case), as it measures its contents and finds a good layout. I guess environments like align have a similar problem.

Is there a way of getting round this multiple evaluation, apart from putting a \clearSum at the beginning of the document?

Comment: From the material in your question this isn't answerable. Can you please create a minimal document that shows this behaviour and which we can actually compile? My first guess would've been that "some kind of table" is an `tabularx`, which evaluates its contents twice. But then you'd have to put your `\clearSum` inside that table... So without code we can test, we can't really answer.

Comment: Sure, will do in just a moment.

Comment: @Skillmon i would guess tabulary if it's always twice

Comment: Have made a major edit.

Comment: @SvenForkbeard Maybe interesting for your usecase: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab

Comment: @JohnKormylo the MWE uses floating point numbers.

Comment: @JohnKormylo See Skillmon's comment . Obviously I could do a hackish solution with counters but that would be pretty ugly and apparently unnecessary. Counters are not designed to be used in the way I require.

Answer (score 2):

Your example had a `c` column in which case `tabularx` should not be used and the problem would go. With `X` you can reset your macro at the point tx resets latex counters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\TX@trial\TX@ckpt{\TX@ckpt\clearSum}{}{}
\makeatother
\newcommand\mySum{0}
\newcommand\clearSum{\renewcommand\mySum{0}}
\newcommand\addToSum[1]{\xdef\mySum{\fpeval{\mySum + #1}}}

\newcommand{\newNumber}[1]{%%%%
    \addToSum{#1}%%%%
    % Print number:
    #1 \\%%
}   
    
\newenvironment{RunningCount}
{%%%%%
    % Open environment:
    \noindent\tabularx{\linewidth}{X}
}
{
    % Close environment:
    \endtabularx
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{RunningCount}
        \newNumber{0.435}
        \newNumber{0.764}
        Total: \mySum
    \end{RunningCount}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think David Carlisle's answer is probably better, but this is perhaps also useful for people in a similar predicament. After a little experimentation I got it working by putting a `\clearSum` in the environment opening, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand\mySum{0}
\newcommand\clearSum{\renewcommand\mySum{0}}
\newcommand\addToSum[1]{\xdef\mySum{\fpeval{\mySum + #1}}}

\newcommand{\newNumber}[2]{
    %% ORDER MATTERS:
    \addToSum{#2}
    % Print number:
    #1 & #2 \\
}   
    
\newenvironment{RunningCount}
{
    % Open environment:
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{X | r}

    %% ORDER MATTERS:
    Desc & Count \\
    \clearSum
}
{
    % Close environment:
    & Total: \mySum
    \endtabularx
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{RunningCount}
        \newNumber{First no:}{0.4}
        \newNumber{Second no:}{0.3}
        \newNumber{Third no:}{0.2}
        \newNumber{Fourth no:}{0.1}
    \end{RunningCount}
\end{document}
```

The two places where I have marked `%% Order matters:` are the crucial point, and the fact that there are two of them makes this a slightly subtle point. In particular, the \clearSum must happen at the end of the environment opening and not like

```
\newenvironment{RunningCount}
    {
        % Open environment:
        \tabularx{\linewidth}{X | r}

        %% ORDER IS INCORRECT. Will behave strangely:
        \clearSum
        Desc & Count \\
    }
   {
       ...
```

whilst replacing the relevant part of the above code with the following also produces the wrong answer:

```
\newcommand{\newNumber}[2]{
        %% ORDER IS INCORRECT. Will behave strangely:
        % Print number:
        #1 & #2 \\
        \addToSum{#2}
    }
```

I think both of these are to do with the way tabularx carries out multiple parses.